# MYSQL multible inner join too long time

Tags: mysql, indexing, inner-join, laravel-query-builder

I built a query with multiple Inner join and it is taking too long time to execute.

I think it's happens because of tables indexes

the query statement is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `result_authors`.`id`,
    `result_authors`.`name`,
    `result_authors`.`author_id`,
    `platforms`.`platform`
FROM
    `result_authors`
        INNER JOIN
    `results` ON `result_authors`.`result_id` = `results`.`id`
        INNER JOIN
    `queries` ON `queries`.`id` = `results`.`query_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `wall_queries` ON `wall_queries`.`query_id` = `queries`.`parent_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `walls` ON `walls`.`id` = `wall_queries`.`wall_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `platforms` ON `result_authors`.`platform_id` = `platforms`.`id`
WHERE
    `walls`.`id` = 2
GROUP BY `result_authors`.`author_id` , `result_authors`.`id` , `result_authors`.`name` , `result_authors`.`profile` , `result_authors`.`platform_id` , `platforms`.`platform`
ORDER BY `result_authors`.`name` ASC;
```

Query Explain

```
+------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------------+------+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
|  id  | select_type |                                                     table                                                      |                id                | select_type |               table                |  id  | select_type |                    table                     |
+------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------------+------+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
| NULL | const       | PRIMARY                                                                                                        | PRIMARY                          |           8 | const                              |    1 |         100 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| NULL | ref         | wall_queries_query_id_foreign,wall_queries_wall_id_foreign                                                     | wall_queries_wall_id_foreign     |           8 | const                              |    1 |         100 | NULL                                         |
| NULL | ref         | PRIMARY,queries_parent_id_index                                                                                | queries_parent_id_index          |           8 | db_name.wall_queries.query_id      |    1 |         100 | Using where; Using index                     |
| NULL | ref         | PRIMARY,results_query_id_foreign,results_query_id_index                                                        | results_query_id_foreign         |           9 | db_name.queries.id                 | 6402 |         100 | NULL                                         |
| NULL | ref         | result_authors_platform_id_foreign,result_authors_result_id_foreign,result_authors_result_id_platform_id_index | result_authors_result_id_foreign |           8 | db_name.results.id                 |    1 |         100 | Using where                                  |
| NULL | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                                                                        | PRIMARY                          |           4 | db_name.result_authors.platform_id |    1 |         100 | NULL                                         |
+------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------------+------+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

this code taking more than 15 minutes to get 28000 row.

**Tables**

Table : result_authors

```
+----+------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | author_id  |     name      |              profile              | result_id | platform_id |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |  420000242 | Author Name 1 | https://twitter.com/profile_slug1 |     15452 |           2 | 2017-11-24 13:55:41 | 2017-11-24 14:13:13 |
|  2 |  400070242 | Author Name 2 | https://twitter.com/profile_slug2 |      5225 |           2 | 2017-11-24 13:58:03 | 2017-11-24 14:13:13 |
|  3 | 2200059092 | Author Name 3 | https://twitter.com/profile_slug3 |       487 |           2 | 2017-11-24 19:48:55 | 2017-11-24 19:48:55 |
+----+------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Table:queries

```
+----+---------------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
| id |     title     |  type   | parent_id | category_id |     updated_at      |
+----+---------------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Query title 1 | public  |         1 |           5 | 2017-10-24 13:21:17 |
|  2 | Query title 2 | private |         2 |           1 | 2017-10-31 16:23:09 |
|  3 | Query title 3 | public  |         1 |           5 | 2017-10-31 16:20:38 |
+----+---------------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Table : walls

```
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| id |     name     |     updated_at      |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 10 | Wall title 1 | 2017-11-16 13:42:32 |
| 11 | Wall title 2 | 2017-11-16 15:01:49 |
| 12 | Wall title 3 | 2017-11-19 12:05:18 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
```

Table : platforms

```
+----+-----------+------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | platform  |            module            |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+-----------+------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | facebook  | \platforms\FacebookPlatform  | 2017-09-15 00:54:49 | 2017-09-15 00:54:49 |
|  2 | twitter   | \platforms\TwitterPlatform   | 2017-09-15 00:54:49 | 2017-09-15 00:54:49 |
|  3 | wordpress | \platforms\WordpressPlatform | 2017-09-15 00:54:49 | 2017-09-15 00:54:49 |
+----+-----------+------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Results looks like**

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| id |   name   | author_id | platform |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Author 1 |       123 | twitter  |
|  3 | Author 2 |       124 | facebook |
|  8 | Author 3 |       125 | twitter  |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Any help to improve performance of the sql query?

> Note: I'm using laravel query builder.

Comment: why don't you use eloquent? and you should paginate all the records instead of fetching all at once.

Comment: Here `GROUP BY` makes no sense and consider it as unnecessary

Comment: Authors duplicated if no `group by`

Comment: @PrateikDarji the same result if I use eloquent and I can't use pagination because I need a list of authors in a drop-down list.. I have many queries like this one... so I need to know how to improve the performance.

Comment: Could you add information on how you index your table fields? In general, fields involved in WHERE and JOIN...ON should be indexed. Also, consider adding foreign index constraint to the IDs involved in JOIN...ON.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: there is one option for dropdown also, you can use select2 and remote data by providing limit and search https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax check this out

Comment: @PrateikDarji Ok .. I can do ajax with select2 but I need improve performance of this query because I have many queries not in dropdown list... and can't use pagination .. I use it  to draw charts .

Comment: That `EXPLAIN` is messed up; try again.  We need to see which table was the 4th in the list.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.